# Hook Rails Engine into global layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hook, rails-engines

I'm currently writing a modular rails app where every functionality is inside a rails engine. I've set up my first engine and everything's working fine so far. now I'm wondering what is the best way to hook the engine into my global navigation that is currently rendered in `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`, like this:

```
%nav#main-nav
  %ul
    %li
      = link_to "Users", users_path, :class => "no-submenu settings"
      %ul
        %li ...
```

The closest thing I found was the `HookListener` of [spree](http://spreecommerce.com/), which uses the deface gem. unfortunately deface only works with html/erb output since it parses the DOM with nokogiri, which isn't the best idea anyway.

Comment: Could you post a bit of your haml files to show how it should fit?

Comment: currently the navigation is a list. it is planned to support at most on sub-level, which is also a list, like this:

        %nav#main-nav
          %ul
            %li= link_to "Users", users_path, :class => "no-submenu settings"

Comment: tip: you can edit your question to put the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the record, i've solved it like this:

- move the base app to an engine/gem as well to make it easily require'able
- add a `Navigation` class
- register into this class from `MyEngine`

`core/lib/navigation.rb`:

```
class Navigation

  @registered_blocks = {}

  class << self
    def register(name, &block)
      @registered_blocks[name] ||= block
    end

    def bind(root)
      @registered_blocks.each do |name, block|
        block.call(root)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`myext/lib/myext/engine.rb`:

```
Navigation.register :myext do |root|
  root.item :mylink, "My Link", "/"
end
```

`config/navigation.rb` (for `simple-navigation`):

```
navigation.items do |root|
  Navigation.bind(root)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

create a module in your app, which you'll include in every engine, e.g. `MyAppModule`

```
class CmsModule::Railtie < ...
  include MyAppModule
end
```

then use the `included` hook to register your navigation etc with your application. you can encapsulate all your hooks etc within the `MyAppModule`, providing a consistent integration for all your engines.

Comment: can you give an example of self.included? ideally an engine should be able to call `add_navigation "title", url, {sub-list here}` or sth like that on the class level

Comment: also: since `Bundle.require` in `config/application.rb` needs this module, where is the best place to put this? i've tested it by putting the module in `config/application.rb` but that will get messy sooner or later